# How to deal with gas all day from nitric oxide?

Tags: supplements

I've started taking supplements that contain L-Arginine.  The results so far have been amazing, except for the fact that the days I take the supplement I have gas all day and need to excuse myself about 3-4 times a day at work to get a desperately needed release.

Is there some issue with the way or time I take the supplement, or maybe there's something I can do to reduce the gas build-up.

I take [naNO Vapor Hardcore Pro Series](http://www.muscletech.com/products/nanovapor/index.shtml) in the morning about 30 minutes before training?

Comment: I've tried to take the supplement earlier, maybe I wasn't taking it  at least 30 minutes before the workout.  Started having gas before going to the gym.  Had a wicked workout, and then after, nothing. So that may have solved the problem.

Comment: I would suggest putting that in as an answer @Salsero69

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried to take the supplement earlier, maybe I wasn't taking it at least 30 minutes before the workout. Started having gas before going to the gym. Had a wicked workout, and then after, nothing. So that may have solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Don't take Nitric Oxide supplements, they are a scam.  It causes gastric distress in everyone (unless you are not taking the suggested dose), and it has no effect on glycogen storage.  It also does not effect blood flow when taken orally.  You are being duped.

Comment: Actually I don't agree.  Plus everything I have read suggests otherwise.  Do you have anything to back up your claim.

Comment: Nothing personal, just trying to save you some money.  A few studies have found some moderate gain in peak power, but mostly no effect or negative effects on strength, body comp and aerobic capacity.  Here is just one of many examples.  [Actual Study](http://www.nutritionjrnl.com/article/S0899-9007(06)00242-5/abstract)

Comment: In my experience it seems to have improved my peak power.  And I actually do feel a difference when I push the weights. I no longer feel like I'm pushing against a brick wall, but more like a rubberized wall. And my recovery time is now amazing.  Bit I am reading the study you provided.

Answer (score 0):

Nitric oxides supps do work to an extent, however a recent study at my uni proved beetroot juice to be just as effective!

Comment: Would be cheaper.  But I like the supplement I'm taking now and have more of less figured out the exact timing of when to take it.

Comment: Care to add a reference to your answer @Mejd?